# ui-grid - Change to allowCellFocus property of columnDef continue to allow the exchange of focus

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I'm trying to disable the row selection on my ui-grid when a condition is reached.

Example: I have a master/slave grid. When i'm adding a new record on the slave, i want to disable the row selection on masters grid.

The problem is, that i currently have the columnDef allowCellFocus as true, and when a cell is focused, an event is trigged which selects the cell row. I need to change the allowCellFocus property to true. But the grid still allowing the user to select another rows.

I'm using the follow code:

```
         function masterDisable() {
            scope.handler.setReadOnly(true);
            scope.enable = false;
            scope.gridOptions.enableRowSelection = false;
            disableGridCellFocus();
            scope.gridApi.core.notifyDataChange(scope.uiGridConstants.dataChange.OPTIONS);
            scope.handler.disableMasters();
        }

        function disableGridCellFocus(){
          scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.forEach(function(element){
            element.allowCellFocus = false;
          });
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide a plunker showing the problem? It would make more likely to get someone to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for your response imbalind, i will update with a plunker later! =)